# Strip interface of properties set to values

Tags: typescript

Is there any way to strip out values from an interface:

```
export interface FileQuery {
    kind: 'FileQuery';
    path: string;
    encoding?: FileEncodings | null;
    flag?: FileSystemFlags;
}
```

Where:

```
StripValue<FileQuery>
```

Would not contain `kind`?

Would contain a type that like this:

```
interface Stripped {
    path: string;
    encoding?: FileEncodings | null;
    flag?: FileSystemFlags;
}
```

Comment: Not really clear, what would `StripValue<FileQuery>` be equivalent to?

Answer (score 1):

You could use two interfaces:

```
export interface FileQuery {
    path: string;
    encoding?: FileEncodings | null;
    flag?: FileSystemFlags;
}

export interface SpecialFileQuery implements FileQuery {
    kind: 'FileQuery';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Omit:

```
export type Omit<T, K extends keyof T> = Pick<T, Exclude<keyof T, K>>;

class FileQueryHandler {
    static make (a : Omit<FileQuery, 'kind'>): FileQuery {
        return { kind: 'FileQuery', ...a };
    }
}
```